# can't initialize iptables table 'nat' under qemu

Tags: docker, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-18.04, qemu, docker-networking

I am facing an issue while starting docker inside s390x container **under qemu** on Ubuntu 18.04 host running on amd64.

Steps followed (On amd64 host):

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
docker run --privileged -it s390x/ubuntu:18.04
apt-get update
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=s390x] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
apt-cache policy docker-ce
service  docker start
```

Docker service not starting. /var/log/docker.log shows

```
time="2021-04-01T17:57:26.643424257Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe nf_nat failed with message:  error: exec: \"modprobe\": executable file not found in $PATH"
time="2021-04-01T17:57:26.643706873Z" level=warning msg="Running modprobe xt_conntrack failed with message: error: exec: \"modprobe\": executable file not found in $PATH"
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': iptables who? (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded
```

.

Any settings needs to be changed /steps needs to add?

Answer (score 1):

The error message:

```
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table `nat': iptables who? (do you need to insmod?)
```

states that the `nat` table cannot be found.

This means that your operating system is missing support for NAT. You can load the NAT module by running `modprobe nf_nat_ipv4`.

Comment: On amd64 host, modprobe is available however when i setup qemu and create docker conatiner for s390x, inside this container it couldnt find modprobe.                           #modprobe nf_nat_ipv4
bash: modprobe: command not found

Comment: You can try `insmod` with path to the `nat` module. You need to also ensure that the Docker container has the capability to load kernel modules.

Comment: On rhel8 I needed iptable_nat module to fix same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for docker in docker in cross architectures is not yet supported. if we use -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock , docker will always run as client in s390x container and server from amd64.